# How to switch between multiple while statements in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, switch-statement, pygame

I am working on a program and i need to switch through different loops.
this works thought when i try to switch back to the previous loop i crashes.

Any suggestions?

P.S. the bellow are examples

e.g. Function = Home

(change loop)

Function = txtbox

(change loop)

Function = Home (Crashes here)

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import sys
import os
# set up pygame
pygame.init()




# set up the window
WINDOWWIDTH = 1200
WINDOWHEIGHT = 650
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 1, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Mango")


Function = "Home"

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Fonts", 30)

#colors
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
TEXTCOLORS = (255, 0, 0)


# run the game loop
while Function == "Home":
    # check for the QUIT event
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            Function = "txtbox"
            break


    pygame.display.flip()



while Function == "txtbox":

    events = pygame.event.get()
    # process other events
    for event in events:

          if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            Function = "Home"
            break

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't crash. It simply finishes execution when `Function` is set to "Home" in the last loop. That loop simply ends.

Try enclosing those two while loops inside another while loop that runs forever.

```
while True:
    while Function == "Home":
        # check for the QUIT event
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                Function = "txtbox"
                break


        pygame.display.flip()



    while Function == "txtbox":

        events = pygame.event.get()
        # process other events
        for event in events:

              if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                Function = "Home"
                break

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I confirm it doesn't crash and just terminates as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You're on a good track.

Try this:

- extract every state of your game to a function,
- have a variable that knows which state is currently "active".

Example code:

```
def home():
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        ...

    if something_happened:
        switch_state(txtbox)


def txtbox():
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        ...

    if something:
        switch_state(home)

Function = home  # assign the function itself to a variable

def switch_state(new_state):
    global Function
    Function = new_state

...

while True:
    Function()  # call the function which is currently active
```

Next steps:

- Write the states as objects, instead of functions (so that they can keep some data about themselves - for example you'd have a state "Level" and all data about the particular level in it)
- Instead of one global `Function()`, keep a list of states, so that you can push a new state on top, and then pop it and go back to whatever state you've been on previously. This will let you manage multiple game screens easily.